# Conditional non-equi join in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, inner-join, non-equi-join

I have a dataset with some missing data (in reality <1%). We are going to use data from other sites to fill in the missing data. We have a `data.table` named `dt1`, which contains the data. We have another `data.table` named `dt2` and this is an index of the sites that can be used to replace (`rsite`) the missing data from a site. In `dt1` I would like to create a column in `dt1` named `UsedSite` that records which site the data we end up using are from.

Create some data to use

```
dt1<-data.table(site=c("s1","s1","s2","s2"), x=c(NA, 1, NA,1))
dt2<-data.table(site=c("s1","s1","s2","s2"), rsite=c("s3","s3","s4","s4"))
```

Since only a small fraction of data are missing, start by setting the values of `UsedSite` to `site`

```
dt1[,UsedSite:=site]
```

The following is where I can't figure out how to do this. I want to just replace the `UsedSite` values with `rsite` where `x` is `NA`. Not at all surprisingly, the line below replaces everything - I don't want that. I don't understand how to instruct it to consider only lines where a condition (`is.na(x)`) is being met.

```
dt1[dt2,UsedSite:=rsite, on=.(site)]
```

My natural impulse is to try `dt1[dt2&is.na(x),UsedSite:=rsite, on=.(site)]`, but that doesn't work. Thoughts? I would like to stick with the `data.table` paradigm in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `fcoalesce` here to replace the NA values with the corresponding values of 'rsite'  If it is a non-NA, it won't get replaced as `fcoalesce` will return the first non-NA for each row

```
library(data.table)
dt1[dt2, UsedSite := fcoalesce(as.character(x), rsite), on = .(site)]
```

-output

```
> dt1
   site  x UsedSite
1:   s1 NA       s3
2:   s1  1        1
3:   s2 NA       s4
4:   s2  1        1
```

#### Update

```
dt1[dt2, UsedSite := fifelse(is.na(x), rsite, site), on = .(site)]
```

-output

```
> dt1
   site  x UsedSite
1:   s1 NA       s3
2:   s1  1       s1
3:   s2 NA       s4
4:   s2  1       s2
```

Comment: Interesting, but I would like rows 2 and 4 then to contain 's1' and 's2' as values instead of '1'

Comment: In this example the final output for the UsedSite variable should be s3, s1, s4, s2

Comment: Perfect, your answers for data.table are always the best